# Why can't List<parent> = List<child>?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, inheritance

Why won't the following code work?

```
class parent {}
class kid:parent {}

List<parent> parents=new List<kid>;
```

It seems obvious to me. What's going on here?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885893/how-to-make-a-generic-class-with-inheritance/885925

Comment: Yeah, I figured this question was a dupe, it's just I didn't know what to search for this question as.

Comment: A list of giraffes is not a list of animals. Why? Because you can add a tiger to a list of animals, but not to a list of giraffes. Since the two types have different legal operations, you cannot convert one to the other.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C# does not currently support [covariance](http://tinyurl.com/58gdgo).

It's [coming](http://tinyurl.com/kko7b7) in .NET 4.0, however, on interfaces and delegates.

[Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/) had a very nice [series](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/tags/Covariance+and+Contravariance/default.aspx) on this subject on his blog awhile back. [Visual Studio Magazine](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/Home.aspx) covers it too in a recent [article](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2009/05/01/generic-covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-40.aspx).

Comment: +1: Classic failure of the Liskov substitution principle.  The proposed child is not generally substitutable for the proposed parent, therefore the inheritance is probably ill-conceived.

Answer (score 4):

Besides the lack of generic variance support in C# prior to version 4.0, List is mutable and so cannot safely be covariant.  Consider this:

```
void AddOne<T>(List<T> arg) where T : new()
{
    arg.Add(new T());
}

void Whoops()
{
    List<parent> contradiction = new List<kid>();
    AddOne(contradiction);  // what should this do?
}
```

This would attempt to add a Parent to a List referenced via a List reference, which is not safe.  Arrays are permitted to be covariant by the runtime, but are type-checked at mutation time and an exception is thrown if the new element is not assignable to the array's runtime element type.

Answer (score 2):

The feature you are looking for is called covariance.  It is not supported in C# until version 4.0 and then only on interfaces and delegates.

Some links on the subject

- http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2009/05/01/generic-covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-40.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173174(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the `List<Parent>` contains `List<child>` you can use an extension method to 'convert', (really just take the Parents that ARE of type child and return them in a list. eg something like:

```
  public static List<T> Convert<T, T2>(this List<T2> input) {
      return input.OfType<T>().ToList();
    }
```

Im not sure if this helps you, but my 2 cents worth! I use it quite alot.

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out, this isn't currently supported in C#. In Java, arrays are covariant, and it can cause some problems. Consider your example, the actual list should be a list of "kid", meaning all the objects in it should be "kid"s (or "grandchildren"). But if the reference you're using to access the list is a list of "parent" then you could insert a "parent" into the list which obviously shouldn't happen.