# When should or shouldn't I be using generic type constraints?

Tags: c#, generics, c#-2.0, type-constraints

I've got a base class:

```
public abstract class StuffBase
{
    public abstract void DoSomething();
}
```

And two derived classes

```
public class Stuff1 : StuffBase
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Stuff 1 did something cool!");
    }
    public Stuff1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("New stuff 1 reporting for duty!");
    }
}

public class Stuff2 : StuffBase
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Stuff 2 did something cool!");
    }
    public Stuff1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("New stuff 2 reporting for duty!");
    }
}
```

Okay, now say I've got a list of items:

```
var items = new List<StuffBase>();
items.Add(new Stuff1());
items.Add(new Stuff2());
```

and I want them all to call their DoSomething() method. I could expect to just iterate the list and call their DoSomething() method, so let's say I've got a method to do that called AllDoSomething() that just iterates over the list and does the job:

```
public static void AllDoSomething(List<StuffBase> items)
{
    items.ForEach(i => i.DoSomething());
}
```

What is the practical difference of the following method?

```
public static void AllDoSomething<T>(List<T> items) where T: StuffBase
{
    items.ForEach(i => i.DoSomething());
}
```

Both methods appear in real terms, although being syntactically different, to be doing the same thing.

Are they just different ways of doing the same thing?  I understand generics and type constraints but can't see why I would use one way over the other in this instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because as of yet, C# does not support [Covariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#C.23).

> More formally, in C# v2.0 if T is a
>   subtype of U, then T[] is a subtype of
>   U[], but G is not a subtype of G
>   (where G is any generic type).  In
>   type-theory terminology, we describe
>   this behavior by saying that C# array
>   types are “covariant” and generic
>   types are “invariant”.

*Reference: http://blogs.msdn.com/rmbyers/archive/2005/02/16/375079.aspx*

If you have the following method :

```
public static void AllDoSomething(List<StuffBase> items)
{
    items.ForEach(i => i.DoSomething());
}

var items = new List<Stuff2>();
x.AllDoSomething(items); //Does not compile
```

Where as if you use the generic type constraint, it will.

For more information about Covariance and Contravariance], check out [Eric Lippert's series of posts](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/tags/Covariance+and+Contravariance/default.aspx).

---

Other posts worth reading :

- http://www.pabich.eu/blog/archive/2008/02/12/c-generics---parameter-variance-its-constraints-and-how-it.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/rmbyers/archive/2006/06/01/613690.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228359(VS.80).aspx
- http://www.csharp411.com/convert-between-generic-ienumerablet/
- http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=64042
- [Why can't List<parent> = List<child>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169215/why-cant-listparent-listchild)

Comment: So if I understand correctly: In my example, I couldn't pass an instance of List<Stuff1> or List<Stuff2> without the type constraint, and so would have to pass an instance of List<StuffBase> whereas using the type constraint, I could?

Comment: i.e. AllDoSomething<T>(List<T> items) where T : StuffBase would allow me to pass in instances of List<Stuff1> or List<Stuff2>

Comment: yes, because that way you are 'bypassing' covariance of formal parameters through a simple generic polymorphic constraint

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense. I guess it wasn't that I didn't udnerstand covariance per se, I was just missing the point.  I get it now.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you had a list:

```
List<Stuff1> l = // get from somewhere
```

Now try:

```
AllDoSomething(l);
```

With the generic version, it will be allowed. With the non-generic, it won't. That's the essential difference. A list of `Stuff1` is not a list of `StuffBase`. But in the generic case, you don't require it to be exactly a list of `StuffBase`, so it's more flexible.

You could work around that by first copying your list of `Stuff1` into a list of `StuffBase`, to make it compatible with the non-generic version. But then suppose you had a method:

```
List<T> TransformList<T>(List<T> input) where T : StuffBase
{
    List<T> output = new List<T>();

    foreach (T item in input)
    {
        // examine item and decide whether to discard it,
        // make new items, whatever
    }

    return output;
}
```

Without generics, you could accept a list of `StuffBase`, but you would then have to return a list of `StuffBase`. The caller would have to use casts if they knew that the items were really of a derived type. So generics allow you to preserve the actual type of an argument and channel it through the method to the return type.

Comment: So the essential difference is that my list couldn't be defined as a list of my derived type - while a list of my base class could contain my derived types?

Comment: The thing remember is that a variable of type `List<B>` cannot have an object of type `List<D>` assigned to it, even though a variable of type `B` can accept a `D`. It's because a class like List can have a method like `Add`. If a variable is a `List<D>`, you should not be able to silently convert it to a `List<B>`, because that would allow `B` objects to be added to it (when it's actually a `List<D>`).

Answer (score 0):

In the example you provided there is no difference but try the following:

```
List<Stuff1> items = new List<Stuff1>();
items.Add(new Stuff1());
AllDoSomething(items);
AllDoSomething<StuffBase>(items);
```

The first call works well but the second one does not compile because of generic covariance