# inheritance and container in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, containers, upcasting

I work in C# here,
let's say i have:

```
class A
{}

class B : A
{}

List<B> myList;
```

I would like, in a part of the code cast this myList as `List< A>,` but when I try to, I get an error:

```
List<A> myUpcastedList = (List<A>)myList; //not working
```

is it possible to do it ? if yes, what is the syntax ?

Comment: Why do you need to cast it to the base class? You can use it without casting. And I don't think what you're trying to do is possible because the List<B> or List<A> are not the type itself but the containers of the types A and B. I might be mistaken but I think what you're trying to do is not possible this way.

Comment: I have a function taking a list, a position and a range and returning a new list with every object in range, I wanted it to be generic, but i guess i'll juste duplicate my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A list of tigers cannot be used as a list of animals, because you can put a turtle into a list of animals but not into a list of tigers.

In C# 4 and 5 this is legal if you use `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `List<T>` because there is no way to put a turtle into a sequence of animals. So you can say:

```
List<B> myList = new List<B>();
IEnumerable<A> myUpcastedList = myList; // legal
```

Comment: I used IEnumerable once when creating a custom container and wanted to be able to "foreach" it. I dont understand what it's suposed to do here

Comment: @Titan: An "enumerable" is a sequence of items; that's why you can "foreach" it. If you want to treat a list of tigers as a sequence of animals, that's legal. If you want to treat a list of tigers as a list of animals, that's illegal because if it were legal then you could insert a turtle into the list of animals, but it is really a list of tigers. Since there is no "insert" method on `IEnumerable<T>`, we can make it legal.

Answer (score 5):

`List<B>` cannot be casted to `List<A>`. You have to create new `List<A>` and fill it with items from source commection. You can use LINQ to Objects for that:

```
var aList= bList.Cast<A>().ToList();
```

You should also read a bit about covariance and contravariance, e.g. on [Eric Lippert’s Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/covariance+and+contravariance/)

Comment: Eric Lippert's current series on Monads is also relevant (though more advanced): http://ericlippert.com/2013/02/21/monads-part-one/

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware this is not possible. An alternative would be to do the following.

```
using System.Linq;

var myUpcastedList = myList.Cast<A>().ToList();
```

Comment: `Cast<A>` return `IEnumerable<A>`, not `List<A>`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to:

```
List<A> myUpcastedList = myList.ToList<A>();
```

this makes a copy of the list though... not sure that's what you intended

Answer (score 1):

You can use this question maybe [useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169215/why-cant-listparent-listchild) for you

```
List<A> testme = new List<B>().OfType<A>().ToList();
```

Comment: So you make a new list based on the first list, without using the first list?