# Cast <T> to List

Tags: c#, generics

I have a method which accepts Generic Type. I want to cast it to List. I tried it with the following example. I am a novice in Generics.Below is what I tried.

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Employee emp = new Employee();
            emp.Name = "a";
            emp.Id = 1;
            List<Employee> empList = new List<Employee>();
            empList.Add(emp);
            get(emp);
            get(empList);
        }

        public static void get<T>(T targetObj)
        {
            if (targetObj.GetType().IsGenericType)
            {
                 Base baseDo = targetObj as Base;//Getting null
                 List<Base> baseList = targetObj as List<Base>;//Getting null
            }
            else
            {
                Base p = targetObj as Base;
            }
        }
    }
    public class Base
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
    }
    public class Employee : Base
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: `IsGenericType` is only `true` when `get()` is called with `empList`. And `empList` is of type `List<Employee>`. This is a different (and not assignable) type than `Base` or `List<Base>` (classes are invariant, `List<Employee>` is _not_ assignable to `List<Base>`). Thatswhy the `as` operators return `null`.

Comment: Well a `List<Employee>` isn't a `List<Base>`, for reasons that are covered elsewhere. You could cast to `IEnumerable<Base>` though...

Comment: In C# `List<Employees>` can't be casted to `List<Base>` Mode details here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169215/why-cant-listparent-listchild

Comment: Use Linq to Cast from one type to another like: var employeeList = targetObj as List<Employee>; var baseList = **employeeList.Cast<Base>().ToList()**;