# Solution to the lack of covariance with generics in c# 2.0 (BindingList)

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, covariance, bindinglist

It's a design question. I have a business object, and 5 business object types that are derived from it.

I also will have a class which has BindingList as a member. I will have 5 classes derived from it.

Since covariance doesn't work here, how would you structure the design to minimize code repetition? I could of course chuck the BindingList and go with DataTable in which case the problem is eliminated.

But since everyone raves about BindingList I would LOVE to see how you guys would approach this.

SOLUTION (based on Pavel Minaev's answer):

```
public class SampleBase
    {
        protected string m_seq;
        protected string m_id;
        protected string m_weight;
        protected string m_units;       

        public SampleBase(string seq, string id, string weight, string units)
        {
            Seq = seq;
            Id = id;
            Weight = weight;
            Units = units;
        }

        public SampleBase() { }

        public string Seq
        {
            get { return m_seq; }
            set { m_seq = value; }
        }

        public string Id
        {
            get { return m_id; }
            set { m_id = value; }
        }

        public string Weight
        {
            get { return m_weight; }
            set { m_weight = value; }
        }

        public string Units
        {
            get { return m_units; }
            set { m_units = value; }
        }

    }

    public class FwdSample : SampleBase
    {
        protected string m_std_id;

        public FwdSample() { }

        public FwdSample (string seq, string id, string weight, string units, string std_id ) : base(seq, id, weight, units)
        {
            StdId = std_id;
        }

        public string StdId 
        {
            get { return m_std_id; }
            set { m_std_id = value; }
        }
    }
    //End of Sample Classes





    public abstract class RunBase<T> where T : SampleBase , new()
    {
        protected BindingList<T> m_samples;



        public RunBase() {}

        public void Add(T sample)
        {
            m_samples.Add(sample);
        }

        public void Update(int index, T sample)
        {
            m_samples[index] = sample;
        }

        public void Delete(int index)
        {
            m_samples.RemoveAt(index);
        }



        public BindingList<T> Samples
        {
            get { return m_samples; }
        }
    }


    public class FwdRun : RunBase<FwdSample>
    {

        public FwdRun()
        {
            m_samples = new BindingList<FwdSample>();
        }


    }
```

Comment: Should clients of your class only be able to retrieve items from that `BindingList`, or add new items to it as well?

Comment: Remember to mark an answer if you get a satisfactory one.

Comment: In the updated code, you use the `new()` generic constraint, but I don't see why it would actually be needed (you don't instantiate any `T` objects).

Comment: I will later when using Add function. I will do something like 

samples.Add(new FwdSample(blah, blah, etc));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your `BindingList` member is private (or protected), and isn't otherwise exposed in your class API, you'd probably want something like this:

```
  class Base
  {
      // No BindingList here. All members that don't need it should be here
      ...
  }

  class Base<TDerived> : Base where TDerived : Base<TDerived>
  {
       BindingList<TDerived> list = new BindingList<TDerived>();

       // All members that need BindingList should be here
  }

  class Derived1 : Base<Derived1> { ... }
  class Derived2 : Base<Derived2> { ... }
  ...
```

Comment: it's not exposed in UI. I will take a look at this closely - brain is too fried now. thanks

Comment: I don't mean the UI here. "Clients of the class" means code that is creating and using objects of the class.

Comment: +1 - I'm curious if there's a specific reason you chose to separate Base and Base<TDerived? It seems to me that Base<TDerived> where TDerived : Base<TDerived> would be sufficient.

Comment: Mainly so that those members of `Base` that don't depend on `TDerived` can be in a single common base class, and algorithms that only need those members can just work with references of that class.

Comment: Could you please explain the following:
class Base<TDerived> : Base where TDerived : Base<TDerived>
?

Comment: Dahlbyk's comment is utterly confusing me - isn't it exactly what Pavel wrote????

Comment: His comment was about the need for class `Base` (you can skip it, and put everything into `Base<TDerived>`, if you don't really need the common base class for your entities).

Comment: The type constraint simply says that `TDerived` must be a class that inherits from `Base<TDerived>`. In other words, it enforces the recursive pass-itself-to-base-class-type-parameter pattern that is used here.

Comment: Sorry, Pavel. I am just not getting it - why are you making it so complex? I just want a simple clean solution; is there a real valid reason to make it so complicated?

Comment: If you find it complex, then simply do not use the generic type constraint.

Comment: I got it. I did something similar to your suggestion, only simpler. 

I will post the solution in the body of the question.

Answer (score 1):

This example only works with .net 3.5 or higher. :(

Perhaps a property that returns all of the inherited objects.  I had a similar question and using System.Linq.  Here is what I used:

```
List<A> testme = new List<B>().OfType<A>().ToList();
```

Or cast all of them to the parent:

```
List<A> testme = new List<B>().Cast<A>().ToList();
```

The above code was from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885893/how-to-make-a-generic-class-with-inheritance/885925#885925).  Thanks Matt.

Comment: I just checked on msdn and apparently System.Linq is not supported in Compact Framework.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an inheritance relationship between the children, why not use `BindingList<TheBaseClass>` as your main collection type?

The most prominent example of when you would need to use covariance is when you wanted to treat a `BindingList<TheDerivedClass>` as `BindingList<TheBaseClass>`.  Can you give us a specific example of where this is tripping you up?  Many of the scenarios for which coviarance is an anaswer can also be solved with a combination of generics, constraints and occasionally additional interfaces.

Comment: will try to explain. I have a grid with samples. There are 6 types of samples; each type has different columns in the grid (some are common to several types). So naturally, I created a SampleBase object and wanted to derive 6 types from that. Then I also have Run object which contains BindingList of SampleBase, since there are 6 types of run as well (type of sample = type of run for the sake of simplicity) - I have 6 objects that derived from RunBase. I may be over complicating it; but I am trying hard to have good design with minimal code repetition. I hope I am being clear.

Comment: oh and a grid can only display one run type(sample type) at a time. So say there are 100 samples displayed in the grid, there are all of the same type.

Comment: From your description, it sounds like you just need to make your `Run` class generic on the type of your business object.

Comment: Pavel, that's what I was trying to do. But since I can't cast generics, how would I proceed? No one here is really giving me a clear answer. I might just stick with the DataTable.

Comment: One thing i forgot to mention as well is that there are 6 types of runs - each run treats the list of samples differently. That's what is basically tripping me up. My idea was to have a RunBase object that has a BindingList of SampleBase objects. Then each run/sample type inherits from RunBase and SampleBase respectively. Turned out I can't do that. So now I am stuck and I am not sure how to proceed. I am refactoring it by the way - I have DataTable (instead of BindingList) and a lot of switch statements right now for different types of runs/samples.